# SQL Insert from other table with Same Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table1 and Table2 have same schema, same columns and same types, and Table2 is empty while Table1 has some data

```
Insert into Table2 values(Select * from Table1)
```

how to transfer the data with sql statement? i think syntax is valid in oracle, but how to do with sql-server

Answer (score 7):

You can leave out the `values` statement:

```
insert into table2
    select * from table1
```

That said, you should really be in the habit of listing column names, both for the `insert` and `select` in this case.  The columns could have the same name and type -- but be in different order.

Answer (score 0):

You might possibly want to drop table 2 and then do a select * into table2 from table1. This way you are guaranteed to have the same structure. Because when somebody changes the structure of either table, but not the other, insert into will bomb.